# Best way to setup RSS feed for a custom WP blog plugin

Tags: rss, blog

Created a new completely custom plugin and created a new type called BlogType, and I can create blog posts inside the admin panel. Now, the question is how to set up RSS feed. I would like to not use a paid service, so I was thinking I would have to setup a cronjob and then allow users to enter their emails and every midnight I would have to post last day's RSS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
 <title>RSS Title</title>
 <description>This is an example of an RSS feed</description>
 <link>http://www.example.com/main.html</link>
 <pubDate>Sun, 06 Sep 2009 16:20:00 +0000</pubDate>

 <item>
  <title>Example entry</title>
  <description>Here is some text containing an interesting description.</description>
  <link>http://www.example.com/blog/post/1</link>
  <pubDate>Sun, 06 Sep 2009 16:20:00 +0000</pubDate>
 </item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

They would all get an email like this with in their email from the post's data. Now, I am not sure if a RSS feed is just a feed of XML formatted data you receive every day or every time you post something. Does this make any sense? I am not too familiar with RSS, because I never used it, but I think I understand the gist of it. And is there a better way?

Comment: You can not `push` RSS  as it is READ ONLY.

Comment: That's one thing I don't understand. How do you insure emails can subscribe to a RSS feed if you can't send emails data in RSS form?

Comment: You don't, you've misunderstood what RSS is. Emails do not subscribe to RSS, RSS is an XML format that RSS reader applications can retrieve for viewing by visiting a URL to retrieve data, it has nothing to do with email. When people subscribe to an RSS feed, it means they put that feeds URL in their reader application which fetches it at regular intervals and display the results, e.g. https://theoldreader.com/ or Feedly. It isn't a way to build email newsletters/subscriptions.

Comment: How do I create a widget that allows people to subscribe to it then? Because it looks to me that the widget would need to add the RSS feed inside the web app people are using for their email address then.

Comment: Because I was told to create a WP widget that allows people to put their names and email addresses and it would allow them to receive the feed.